# making a matrix from different files in linux

Tags: linux

In directory named `output`, I have 500 directories names `sample1_ouput ----- sample500_output`
For example, three files namely `sample1_output sample2_output sample3_output`
Each `*_output` directory has a `quant.sf` file with header:

Name    Length  EffectiveLength TPM NumReads

quant.sf File 1:

```
Name    Length  EffectiveLength TPM NumReads
S1  681 459.000 0.000000    0.000
S2  816 594.000 0.000000    0.000
S3  1665    1330.658    0.047059    1.000
S4  821 599.000 0.000000    0.000
S5  252 48.000  0.000000    0.000
S6  180 13.000  0.000000    0.000
S7  507 285.000 0.000000    0.000
S8  498 276.000 0.000000    0.000
S9  327 108.000 0.000000    0.000
```

quant.sf File 2:

```
Name    Length  EffectiveLength TPM NumReads
S1  681 458.000 0.000000    0.000
S2  816 593.000 0.000000    0.000
S3  1665    1442.000    0.000000    0.000
S4  821 598.000 0.000000    0.000
S5  252 49.000  0.000000    0.000
S6  180 14.000  0.000000    0.000
S7  507 284.000 0.000000    0.000
S8  498 275.000 0.000000    0.000
S9  327 108.000 0.000000    0.000
```

quant.sf File 3:

```
Name    Length  EffectiveLength TPM NumReads
S1  681 456.000 0.000000    0.000
S2  816 591.000 0.000000    0.000
S3  1665    1440.000    0.000000    0.000
S4  821 596.000 0.000000    0.000
S5  252 48.000  0.000000    0.000
S6  180 13.000  0.000000    0.000
S7  507 282.000 0.050000    0.000
S8  498 273.000 0.000000    0.000
S9  327 106.000 0.000000    0.000
```

I want to make one file with column 1 as `Name` and then `TPM` columns from all the files making 501 columns in total for final file. I want each TPM column to have same name as of sample directory name by getting rid off suffix `_output`.Final sample output file:

```
Name sample1 sample2 sample3
S1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
S2 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
S3 0.047059 0.000000 0.000000
S4 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
S5 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
S6 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
S7 0.000000 0.000000 0.050000
S8 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
S9 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

I tried:

```
paste *sf | cut -f 1,4,9,14-----n | grep -v "TPM"  > output
```

But it extracts Name column more than once.

Comment: So you want to `join` the files... but it's going to be hard for 500 files. Please post sample 3 files with sample like 10 lines each and sample output you want to get. What character separates the columns? A tabulation?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have edited the original question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First extract the name column. Then for each of the files, extract the TPM column and join with the result. Print the result.

```
output=
for f in *.sf; do
   if [[ -z "$output" ]]; then
        # Initialize output with the name column from any file that is first
        output=$(cut -f1 "$f")
   fi
   # join output with the 4rth column from file
   output=$(paste <(printf "%s\n" "$output") <(
       echo "$f"
      cut -f4 "$f" | tail -n+2
   ))
done
printf "%s\n" "$output"
```

[Tetsed on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/WearableDimpledHypertalk)/

I believe with `columns` utility you could do:

```
count=$(printf "%.1s" *.sf | wc -c)
{ printf "%s\n" *.sf | head -n1 | xargs cut -f1;  cut -f2 *.sf; } |
columns --by-columns -w1 -c$((count + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! It only gave two columns. One Name and other TPM (I think just for one sample file)

Comment: Edited, added test on repl, added that the first line should be filename.